# Swift extension event listener on property

Tags: ios, swift, properties, uikit

I was wondering is it possible to edit `properties` in Swift through and `extension`?

I want to do something like this.

```
extension UIGestureRecognizer {
    var state: UIGestureRecognizerState {
       didSet(state) {
             self.stateChanged(state)
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the implementation of `UIGestureRecognizer`'s `state` property. If you could publicly get and set `state`, then you could create a different computed property `myState` that forwarded get and set to `state`. Unfortunately you can't. You can however get around this using KVO ([Key Value Observing](http://nshipster.com/key-value-observing/)).

First off, we create an object that can respond to KVO notifications for our gesture and implement `observeValueForKeyPath` which is called when the `state` property is called.

```
class StateObserver : NSObject {
    override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
        if let gesture = object as? UIGestureRecognizer {
            gesture.stateChanged(gesture.state)
        }
    }
}
```

Second, register a `StateObserver` instance to get notified when `tap.state` is changed.

```
let stateObserver = StateObserver()
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer()
tap.addObserver(stateObserver, forKeyPath: "state", options: [.New, .Old], context: nil)
```

Third, don't forget to unregister `StateObserver` once you're done.

```
tap.removeObserver(stateObserver, forKeyPath: "state'")
```

Comment: When would you remove the observer? If its on a UITapGesture for instance wouldn't you always want that to be there incase multiple taps?

Comment: You're correct in that you remove the observer when you no longer want to receive notifications. An example would adding the observer when the view appears on screen and removing the observer when the view is removed.